# Multi database development strategies in code

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an application where each user has their own database. I am thinking of splitting into 2 or more sets of severs to distribute the load.

The database that a user has is determined by the URL subdomain

for example:

abc.phpppointofsale.com uses the abc database.

If I add another database server; there are 2 options:

1. Have a database lookup table on one of the database servers that maps subdomain to database server.
2. make the url something like abc-server2.phppointofsale.com (looks odd to user)

The pros and cons that I see is that the 1st method requires that the main server must be up to access application and requires an extra query (but this is fast anyways).

I am leaning towards options 1 because if I need to move databases to other servers the url doesn't change. Is there a better way to do option 1?

Comment: Are these read-only databases? Because once you store the same (user-specific) database on multiple servers you're going to have to worry about keeping them in sync.

Also, why are you splitting a given user's database onto multiple servers? Is the load really going to be that high?

Last but not least, you should look into replication, which handles a lot of this for you.

Comment: They are not read only. I have 300+ databases on server; the load is low; but memory usage keeps going up. I have scripts that can keep schema in sync for each user.

Comment: Method #1 is probably best. I hope you're not running a separate instance of the server for each DB; that would explain the increased memory usage. If that's not the cause, then you should probably investigate what's eating memory.

Comment: You can go with host setting. You will already be setting host. Instead of setting localhost, set host like IP or other url so, both server's database will be having connection based on host and you will not need any additional lookup.

Comment: I am running one mysql instance for the entire server.